# create DOM element in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

its a simple `html` code that i don't know why not work!
`html` file included with a iframe tag with id.
script make a element and try to append that to `iframe`.
its not work and i don't know why its work on (see code commented)!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="s1" src="ifsrc.html"></iframe>

<script>
    var soal = document.createElement("a");
    var soaltext = document.createTextNode("text");
    var soalat = document.createAttribute("class");
    soalat.value = "class ";
    var soalid = document.createAttribute("id");
    soalid.value = "attid";

    soal.setAttributeNode(soalat);
    soal.setAttributeNode(soalid);
    soal.appendChild(soaltext);
    //document.body.appendChild(soal); its work!

    var iFrame =  document.getElementById("s1");
    var iFrameBody;
    iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    iFrameBody.appendChild(soal); // its not work!
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`ifsrc.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
sample text
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Use of document.createAttribute() is deprecated. Use element.setAttribute() instead. test.html:13
Use of setAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use setAttribute() instead.

Comment: works fine for me in FF

Comment: are you loading the page using `http://` protocol or `file://` protocol. If you are using file protocol Same Origin Policy may have an effect

Comment: php storm server. http://localhost:63342

Comment: which is the browser used

Comment: firefox . itest opera and ie . same problem

Answer (score 2):

its work!

```
<script>
    var soal = document.createElement("a");
    var soaltext = document.createTextNode("tgggext");
    soal.appendChild(soaltext);

    alert("ad");

    var iFrame =  document.getElementById("s1");
    var iFrameBody;
    iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    iFrameBody.appendChild(soal);
</script>
```

but its not work!!!

```
<script>
    var soal = document.createElement("a");
    var soaltext = document.createTextNode("tgggext");
    soal.appendChild(soaltext);

    var iFrame =  document.getElementById("s1");
    var iFrameBody;
    iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    iFrameBody.appendChild(soal);
</script>
```

finally i found my problem.its about ready event.
alert have little take time and its Sufficient for iframe to complete load and ready.
i use this code instead of above.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#s1').ready(function(){
        $('#s1').contents().find('body').html("<a>Hey, i`ve changed conten!</a>");
    });
});
```

and its works fine because ready event wait for iframe to load complete.